# Gitlab pipeline description doesn't match as expected

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to write my first GitLab pipeline description. I use the `needs` parameter, and I still don't know why I get this mashed connection setup. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Here is `what` I want to achieve`.

[image]

But instead this is what I get:

[image]

```
foo:
    stage: build

bar:
    stage: build

foo-test:
    stage: test
    needs: ["foo"]

bar-test:
    stage: test
    needs: ["bar"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with this. You should be seeing that `bar-test` starts immediately after `bar` is done.

The UI is currently going through an overhaul as they released this before doing that, hence you're still seeing the joined up pipeline graph.

There's an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/33793) discussing how to resolve this for the future on GitLab.