# Skip one stage for one task in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I made my first gitlab pipeline and I introduced a few stages. One stage is exclusively for one specific OS, so Windows can skip it. This is how it should look like:

[image]

But this is what I get by using the `needs` keyword in my pipeline:

[image]

Although the second task in the `installer` is dependent on the second task of `package`. Why is the dependency going through `notarize` although that's not what my Gitlab pipeline file describes? Am I doing something wrong or is the dependency system (or even just the UI) broken in Gitlab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gitlab pipeline description doesn't match as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312404/gitlab-pipeline-description-doesnt-match-as-expected)

Comment: Could you copy your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file ?